# How to store CSV data in a Nested Dictionary that has a dictionary and a list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I have the following CSV Data,

```
Rule1,Status1,1
Rule1,Status2,1
Rule1,Status3,1
Rule1,Status4,2
Rule2,Status1,2
Rule2,Status2,1
Rule2,Status3,1
Rule2,Status4,3
```

I have unique rules (first column) stored in a list called Rules. I want my dictionary to look like the following:

```
DictionaryFull = {
                  'Rule1' : {1 : [Status1, Status2, Status3], 2 : [Status4]},
                  'Rule2' : {1 : [Status2, Status3], 2 : [Status1], 3 : [Status4]}
                 }
```

Here is what I tried:

```
openfile = ('data.csv', 'rU')
finalfile = csv.reader(openfile, delimiter=',')

FullDictionary = {}

for row in finalfile:
  for j in range (0, 300): #300 number of rules 
    if Rules[j] not in FullDictionary:
        for i in range(1, 71): #These are third column numbers 1 - 71 
            if i == int(row[2]) and row[0] == Rules[j]:
                FullDictionary = {Rules[j] : { i : [].append[row[1]}}
                    print FullDictionary
```

But I am getting the following as the result:

```
{'Rule1': {1 : None}} and so on
```

Am I doing something wrong? How to accomplish this task of having a dictionary with both another dictionary and a list.

I tried this:

```
def something():
    full_dictionary = {}
    with open(DataFilePath) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            rule = row[2], status = row[0], num = int(row[5])
            r = full_dictionary.setdefault(rule, {})
            r.setdefault(num, []).append(status)

    print full_dictionary
```

The error: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hwo about using [`collection.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

full_dictionary = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
with open('data.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for rule, status, num in reader:
        full_dictionary[rule][num].append(status)

print full_dictionary
```

output:

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x00000000025A6438>, {
    'Rule2': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {
        '1': ['Status2', 'Status3'],
        '3': ['Status4'],
        '2': ['Status1']
     }),
     'Rule1': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {
         '1': ['Status1', 'Status2', 'Status3'],
         '2': ['Status4']
     })
})
```

---

If you don't want to use `defaultdict`, you have to care new key.

For example, using [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
import csv

full_dictionary = {}
with open('data.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for rule, status, num in reader:
        r = full_dictionary.setdefault(rule, {})
        r.setdefault(num, []).append(status)

print full_dictionary
```

output:

```
{'Rule1': {'1': ['Status1', 'Status2', 'Status3'], '2': ['Status4']},
 'Rule2': {'1': ['Status2', 'Status3'], '2': ['Status1'], '3': ['Status4']}}
```

Comment: what if I have more than 3 columns in csv? and there is an error "I/O operation on closed file"

Comment: @GravityM, Do you mean there could be arbitrary column numbers? Then, which column should be put into lists?

Comment: @GravityM, I used [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) in the answer. It closes the file at the end of the block. If you want to do something with the file, do it inside the `with` statement block.

Comment: yes, there are row[0], [1], [2], [3], [5], [4]. and I m only taking row[1], row[2] and road [4].

Comment: @GravityM, Replace `for rule, status, num in reader:` with `for row in reader: rule, status, num = row[1], row[2], row[4]`

Comment: @GravityM, Or use `for row in reader`, `row[1]`, `row[2]`, `row[4]` instead of named variables.

Comment: for row in reader: rule, status, num = row[0], row[1], row[2] -- so I would say for rule, status, num = row[0], row[1], row[2]: ??

Comment: @GravityM, No, you can't. Python `for` statement does not allow assignment in the `for ... in`. `for row in reader: rule, status, num = row[1], row[2], row[4]`

Comment: @GravityM, `rule, status, num = row[2], row[0], int(row[5])` please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58046/discussion-between-gravity-m-and-falsetru).

Answer (score 0):

`list.append` returns None, so your assignment `Rules[j] = [].append([row[1])` is setting `Rules[j] = None`.

Amend that to:

```
FullDictionary = {Rules[j] : { i : [row[1]}}
```

or

```
old_value = Rules[j].get(i, [])
old_value.append(row[1])
```

depending on what you're wishing to achieve.

Comment: It worked but it only displays one status. {'Rule1': {1: ['Status1']}} and in the next one it prints Status2. and so on... But i want ['Status1', 'Status2']